# React Native - fetch(url) sempre retornando um Promise

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou iniciando em React Native, não tive problemas até começar a fazer requisições HTTP. Estou usando essa função:

```
async getJSON(url, parameters){
    try{
        //check if URL isn't empty
        if(url.length == 0)
            return false;

        //construct HTTP parameters
        var params = '';
        for (var key in parameters) {
            if(params.length)
                params += "&";

            params += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[key]);
        }
        //doing request
        const response = await fetch(`${url}${params}`);
        let body = await response.json();

        return body;
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Então obtive a Promisse a seguir:

```
Promise {_40: 1, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: Handler}
v
_40:1
_55:{success: false, msg: "segredo não informado"}
_65:1
_72:null
__proto__:Object
```

Esse JSON no objeto _55 é o que desejo obter, poderia simplesmente acessar e pegá-lo, mas isso não seria correto (vai que o número muda, haha).

Então, adaptei o código abaixo a partir [dessa postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760489/5445596), e inseri o código antes do **return body;** do primeiro código.

```
Promise.resolve(body).then(function(value) {
    console.log(value); //aqui deu log do JSON!
    body = value; // essa atribuição não funcionou, por algum motivo
});
```

A atribuição acima deveria passar o JSON para o *body*, mas no final retornou o Promise novamente... Tentei colocar um **await** antes de Promise.resolve mas nada mudou.

Olhei a [documentação](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html), busquei [mais detalhes](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/javascript-assincrono-promises/) e até modelos prontos em respostas aqui no StackOverflow que usam o esquema fetch->then->then. Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Quem sabe usando "state" para gravar o valor... Vou testar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já que o Promise.resolve é assíncrono, dentro de uma função também assíncrona, resolvi o problema colocando ela na classe principal. Funciona assim:

Na classe principal, faço uma chamada ao método que retorna o JSON de um webservice:

```
let result = conn.getJSON(this, url.login, params);
```

> Obs.: O método getJSON permanece igual ao primeiro código da pergunta.

O Objeto **Promise** estará em *result*, então logo abaixo dele faço a tratativa do JSON.

```
if(result){
     Promise.resolve(result).then(function(json) {
       //login successfully
       if(json.success){
         console.warn("loging in...");
       }else{
         console.warn("wrong login");
       }

     });
   }else{
     Alert.alert(
       'Erro LOG-2',
       'Nenhuma informação retornada do servidor. Talvez uma instabilidade na rede tenha causado isso. Tente novamente.',
            [
         {text: 'OK, vou verificar.', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
            ],
       { cancelable: true }
      )
   }
```